# dm-mysql2-adapter (LoadError) but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rubygems

the issue that I'm dealing with is the following. I've installed a brand new ruby environment. In my current project I'ld like to use the following gems:

```
RAILS_VERSION = '~> 3.0.4'
DM_VERSION    = '~> 1.1.0'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Database & ORM
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem 'data_mapper',        DM_VERSION
gem 'dm-mysql-adapter',   DM_VERSION
gem 'dm-rails',           DM_VERSION

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'dm-devise'
```

I have the following database.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: blabla
  password: albalb
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Performing "bundle install" does not result into any kind of error. But as soon as I want to do some thing with the database (like "rails s", or "rake db:migrate") the folling error occurrs:

```
/Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- dm-mysql2-adapter (LoadError)
from /Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Gery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Best Regards,

Gerardo

Comment: If I use the adapter 'mysql', then the following runtime error occurrs while performing an task related to the database: !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2' -

Comment: I got the same error when I had removed mysql2 from database.yml but forgot to remove it from my Gemfile.  The error itself is very misleading! ;)  So make sure you replace it with `mysql` in both database.yml and your Gemfile.

Answer (score 4):

I just went into #datamapper and solnic helped me understand this: there is no need to use the `mysql2` gem with DataMapper, because `do-mysql` (the DataObject driver dm-mysql-adapter depends on to access MySQL repositories) doesn't have problems with character-encodings, which is the reason I (and most people, I would assume) use the `mysql2` driver in ActiveRecord projects.

So the answer is, unless I'm mistaken about why you're using it, remove `mysql2` from your Gemfile and your database.yml file (replace it with `mysql`) and do a new `bundle install`, you shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in dm-core as a result of sub-standard coding. I have committed a hack to fix this hack and submitted a pull request here: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/pull/154